# Relation between Displacement Operator and Winding number

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, topological-insulators, topological-phase

I am trying to implement a paper [https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06086] using quantum computing techniques. In the supplementary material[SM] with the main paper, they introduce a displacement operator and find its relation with the winding number in 1D topological matter which has a floquet Hamiltonian.

I checked out the references [Phys. Rev. B 82, 235114 (2010)] related to the displacement operator in the SM, it sort of makes sense how it is related, because `\Delta{x} = d\epsilon/dt * T` `d\epsilon/dt` is the group velocity, and this is the formula of the winding number. But I did not completely understand this paragraph from the reference paper, particularly why the spin-down qubit does not change its avg position-

> [image: Blockquote]

Also, in this SM of this paper [Phys. Rev. Lett. 125, 160503 (2020)], they plotted the mean displacement as a function of n (which is the number of cycles = trotter steps --> Trotterizing the quantum circuit), and it takes 0 and -1, but I did not understand why it takes a negative value, I can correlate this to v = -2P to some extent, since the winding number v in my case has to be 1 or 0, and so P takes a -1. Because the mean displacement operator in the main paper has been defined as -

> [image: Blockquote]

Clearly, P cannot take negative values because its the sum of x*expectation value of P associated with the qubits at even position of the lattice site x.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.